# How to replace values using Arrays & Ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I can replace values by mentioning them one by one.

I want to replace (oldarray) with (newarray) where both of them are derived from ranges.
i.e. oldarray = ("a2:a5") and newarray = ("b2:b5") instead of writing them one by one.

and also I need to replace each old value with adjacent cell value
i.e. a2 replaced by b2, and a3 replaced by b3.

is that possible?

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
    
    Dim NewValues() As String
    Dim NewValues() As String
    
    OldValues = Split("BMV,MERCE", ",")
    NewValues = Split("Jack,Sally", ",")
    
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(OldValues)
        With sheets("destination").Columns("Z:Z")
        .Replace What:=OldValues(i), Replacement:=NewValues(i), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
        End With
        Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: @41686d6564 I am trying to replace values cell by cell not to (copy and paste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Search and Replace (`Application.Match`)

- If a value in the `Destination` column (`Z`) is found in the `Search` column (`A`), it will be replaced with the value in the same row of the `Replace` column (`B`).
- This search (`Application.Match`) is not case-sensitive i.e. `A = a`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Only run `replaceValues`; the rest is being called by it.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const rFirst As String = "B2"
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "Z2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write from worksheets to arrays.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet   ' Each Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range      ' Each Column Range
    ' Source
    Dim sData As Variant  ' Search Data Array
    Dim rData As Variant  ' Replace Data Array
    Dim ColOffset As Long ' Search and Replace Column Offset
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Set rng = getColumnRange(getCellRange(ws, sFirst))
    ColOffset = getCellRange(ws, rFirst).Column - rng.Column
    sData = getColumn(rng)
    rData = getColumn(rng.Offset(, ColOffset))
    ' Destination
    Dim dData As Variant  ' Destination Array
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(dstName)
    Set rng = getColumnRange(getCellRange(ws, dFirst))
    dData = getColumn(rng)
    
    ' Search and replace (in arrays).
    
    Dim mData As Variant ' Match Data Array
    mData = Application.Match(dData, sData, 0)
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(dData, 1) ' or 'UBound(mData, 1)'
        cMatch = mData(i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
            dData(i, 1) = rData(cMatch, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write from Destination Array to Destination Range.
    
    rng.Value = dData

End Sub

Function getCellRange( _
    ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal CellAddress As String) _
As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getCellRange = ws.Range(CellAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function getColumnRange( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCell
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set rng = rng.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set getColumnRange = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

Function getColumn( _
    rng As Range) _
As Variant
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(rng.Address, ":") > 0 Then
            getColumn = rng.Value
        Else
            Dim Data As Variant
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
            getColumn = Data
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :D this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub ReplaceValues()
    
    Dim OldValues, NewValues, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Config") 'or whichever sheet...
    OldValues = ws.Range("A2:A5").Value 'this gives a 2d array
    NewValues = ws.Range("B2:B5").Value 'this too
    
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(OldValues, 1)
        With sheets("destination").Columns("Z:Z")
        .Replace What:=OldValues(i, 1), Replacement:=NewValues(i, 1), _
                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
        End With
        Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, please check @VBasic2008 Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code below reads the data from A2:A6 into an array `SrcArr` and the data from B2:B6 into another array I called `ModArr`. Then it creates a third array (`OutArr`) of the same size as the source and writes data from `SrcArr` into it modified according to the data in `ModArr`. Finally, the `OutArr` is written to column D. This is the setup and the result.

[image]

And here is the code that did it.

```
Sub ReplaceArray()
    ' 138

    Dim SrcArr      As Variant              ' Source
    Dim ModArr      As Variant              ' Modifier
    Dim OutArr      As Variant              ' Output
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    
    With ActiveSheet
        SrcArr = .Range("A2:A6").Value
        ModArr = .Range("B2:B6").Value
        ReDim OutArr(1 To UBound(SrcArr), 1 To UBound(SrcArr, 2))
        
        For R = 1 To UBound(SrcArr)
            If ModArr(R, 1) = True Then
                OutArr(R, 1) = SrcArr(R, 1) * 12
            Else
                If IsEmpty(ModArr(R, 1)) Then
                    OutArr(R, 1) = "No data"
                Else
                    OutArr(R, 1) = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next R
        
        .Cells(2, "D").Resize(UBound(SrcArr), UBound(SrcArr, 2)).Value = OutArr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, please check @VBasic2008 Answer.